# Local or session language variables

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm building a multi-language site using the internationalization set of modules.
The problem is that I've done any queries to extract for example nodes or taxonomy terms with selection of language in the code(back-end) and what language reference or defauld language value I will use to compare or execute queries? Every user that is connected on the site I think they must have each a variable that indicates the language that the user have choosen and if there isn't, uses the browser language.
I've tried with the global variable $language but this is for all the web site and it's user independent.
I hope you understand my question! Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a filter for **Content  Translation: User's Current Language**, which is the language that an authenticated user has set in the user settings (it is NOT the same as the current browser language or the site language).

**If** no option for the '*User's Current Language*' is available in the filter criteria form, **then** verify your configuration at *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order should be 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User' (as mentioned also in https://www.drupal.org/node/1701854#comment-6279474).

Does this help?